# Flask Electron HTML

Tags: html, flask, npm, electron, exe

I am currently working on a project using Flask as backend and a HTML file as frontend. Trying to use electron for turning it into an exe, I faced some difficulties: I need to run my Flask with the usual flask run command as well as a command for running my HTML file which includes a library that needs 'npm run start'. Both of this task are proceeded nicely. BUT: when running the exe, flask does not work properly. It starts to run again somehow because after a short period of time, some of my python code isn't working anymore. When closing the exe, flask also does not stop which could cause all the other problems with flask.

How do I solve this?

currently my directory is as it follows:
project
.electronAPP (including everything related to electron)
.src (including all flask)
.index.html (my main HTML doc)
... (everything HTML related such as the

here is the content my current main.js file:

```
//FLASK:
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const flaskAppPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src'); 
  console.log(flaskAppPath);
  flaskProcess = spawn('flask run', [], { shell: true, cwd: flaskAppPath });
  console.log(flaskProcess);

//HTML LIB THAT NEEDS NPM
  const npmAppPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', ''); 
  console.log(npmAppPath);
  npmProcess = spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--no-open'], { shell: true, cwd: npmAppPath });
  console.log(npmProcess);

setTimeout(() => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1000,
      height: 800,
      icon: path.join(__dirname, 'favicon.ico'),
      webPreferences: {
        webSecurity: false, 
Sicherheitsrisiken bergen)
        nodeIntegration: true,
      },
    });

    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([]);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8080/main.html');

 [...]
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  flaskProcess.kill('SIGTERM');
  npmProcess.kill();

  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
});


flaskProcess.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
  console.log(`Flask-Server exit-Code: ${code} signal: ${signal}`);
});

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) createWindow();
});
```

Why isn't it working properly?